# При открытии файлов psd в Adobe Photoshop появляются артефакты по всей рабочей области

Tags: photoshop, adobe

При открытии файлов psd в Adobe Photoshop появляются артефакты по всей рабочей области. Иногда просто рабочая область чёрная и всё. Иногда проблема решается перезагрузкой самого ФШ, иногда перезагрузкой ПК. В других редакторах изображений всё работает корректно

С чем это может быть связано?

[image]

ОС: Windows 11 
Фотошоп: 2023

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, больше подозреваю что виноват Crack

Comment: Такое ощущение, что в артефактах зашифровано что-то ..

Comment: У меня артефакты у программ, использующих OCL для работы, могут появиться, если в данный момент рабочая программа использует для тензоров/матриц слишком много памяти на видеоадаптере.

Answer (score 0):

В целом выглядит как замусоренная память на GPU (т.е. сбой в алгоритмах Фотошопа по работе с ней). Решение вероятно где-то в той области.

Кому-то пишут помогло в настройках включить Technology Preview -> Deactivate native canvas button:

[image]

Также может помочь отключить GPU ускорение на вкладке Performance.

И в комментариях верно заметили, если EXEшник патчился, то могло зацепить/недопатчить что-то.

Comment: Попробую, отпишусь, спасибо

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению